# Using system() to execute BASH script outputs: source: not found

Tags: c, bash

all:
    There is a shell script a.sh:

```
#/bin/bash -x -n

source /etc/profile
```

and a test.c program use system() function to invoke this script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    system("/data/nan/a.sh");
    return 0;
}
```

I find when call a.sh directly in console:

```
./a.sh
```

It is OK.

But execute the c program:

```
./test
```

It prints "source: not found".

I know the cause may be system() function use /bin/sh to execute a.sh script. But I add   "#/bin/bash" add the beginning of the a.sh. Why this happens? Thanks very much in advance!

Best Regards
Nan Xiao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `!` in the shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash -x -n
 ^
```